# improving transition smoothness in view

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, catransition, multiple-views

In our application we use CATransition for transition from one view to another, but we are missing the smoothness like in others apps . hence what can be alternate solution for view transition or some tips to improve applicaton flow smoothness.

Regards

Edited here is the code we are using:

```
MyView *obj =[[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,415)];
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush]; 
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];  
[[self.superview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

[self.superview addSubview:obj];
[obj release];

[self removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard to help you without any code/background information, but one things I can tell you is rasterization during animation can make a huge difference:

```
- (void)startAnimation {
    [myView.layer setShouldRasterize:YES]; //tell the layer to rasterize
    [myView.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale]; //make sure it scales on retina devices

    double delayInSeconds = 0.1; // wait a bit to let it rasterize
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^(void) {
        //do
        //your
        //animation
        //here

        //where you're animation is finished (i.e. in a completion block)
        //tell the layer not to rasterize anymore
        [myView.layer setShouldRasterize:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: have edited my question and provided the code block..tried applying rasterization but its not making that much differance

Comment: Can you not use a simple UIView animation? Why do you need Core Animation? Also, try rasterizing the *superview*, not the view itself.